# How do I search what this "MAGETWO-45654" refers to on magento2 github

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1

I'm working on an issue on magento 2.1-develop branch. I was going through this integration test *dev/tests/integration/testsuite/Magento/ConfigurableProduct/Model/OptionRepositoryTest.php*

This test is skipped as the first line of test says

```
$this->markTestSkipped('Test skipped due to MAGETWO-45654');
```

It seems like "MAGETWO-45654" refers to an issue. How do I search for this issue. I tried searching for it by using Github issues filter. I couldn't find the issue. I would like to know how to search for an issue by "MAGETWO-" kind of label.

Answer (score 2):

MAGETWO-* refers to Magento internal issue system, that not public.

Comment: It does answer the question. The MAGETWO- identifier is for Magento's internal systems. You will not be able to find any additional information on that.